# how to create a new report using a shared dataset in BIDS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

Is there a way to configure BIDS so that when you create a new report that you can select a previously created shared dataset instead of having to build a query and then subsituted the shared dataset after the wizard has completed?

currently I am creating the share dataset in BIDS, publishing to the server, and the starting the new report in report builder, downloading the report and then adding the report to my solution and fixing up the shared dataset afterwords. this is clunky to say the least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is create a "template" report with all of the datasets stored in it. Then, I simply add that "template" report to any project it is needed in. With this template I can also include commonly used fields such as runtime of the report, page number, report created by, as well as the company logo and a text box for the title of the report (with the formatting I prefer).

Does this accomplish what you are needing?

Comment: somewhat. for now what I do is author the repots in report builder then edit and adapt the .RDL so that I can be managed/deployed by BIDS.